# ClamAV and UFW on 18.04

Tags: ufw, clamav, gufw, clamtk

I have loaded ClamAV: Ubuntu 18.04.  Ran it and it found a bunch of junk that was deleted.  I also installed ClamTK.

My question is if I activate UFW (would prefer the GUI version) will it cause a problem with ClamAV???  I was thinking in terms of overall performance, checking each other's findings, etc.

Thanks,
Rich Ramik

Answer (score 1):

There is a ufw GUI named `gufw` and it's easy to use, install `gufw` by running:

```
sudo apt install gufw
```

I don't think it will cause any problem with clamav if you allow outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

ufw is a firewall clamav is an antivirus program. They do not interact with each-other and will hence not effect each-others performance.